# json_decode problem with joomla

Tags: php, json, joomla1.5, joomla-k2

I tried searching but could not find. Sorry If have missed if the solution is already present...

Code

> $json =
>   '[{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"1","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":""},{"id":"4","value":""},{"id":"5","value":""},{"id":"6","value":""},{"id":"7","value":""},{"id":"8","value":""},{"id":"9","value":""},{"id":"10","value":"1"}]';

```
$myArray = json_decode($json);
  foreach ($myArray as $key => $v) {
    if ($v->id == 10 && ($v->value == 0 || $v->value == 1)) {
        echo 'Value found at array key ' . $key;
    }
}
```

### OUPUT

Value found at array key 9

But this works only when i statically specify the $json with value in single quotes...But in my joomla project the values is fetched with help of class variable
so when i when i use `$json=$item->extra_fields` instead of giving a static string to `$json` it doesnt work......

code

```
 $json=$item->extra_fields;
  $myArray = json_decode($json);
  foreach ($myArray as $key => $v) {
    if ($v->id == 10 && ($v->value == 0 || $v->value == 1)) {
        echo 'Value found at array key ' . $key;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /components/com_k2/views/item/view.html.php
>   on line 484

---

UPDATE:

```
echo "JSON: $json<br/><br/>";
echo "DUMP: ".var_dump($myArray);
```

### OUTPUT

```
JSON: [{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"1","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":""},
{"id":"4","value":""},{"id":"5","value":""},{"id":"6","value":"<br \/>"},
{"id":"7","value":"<br \/>"},{"id":"8","value":"<br \/>"},{"id":"9","value":"<br \/>"},
{"id":"10","value":"1"}]

NULL DUMP:
```

--> Using true with json_decode doesnt alter the output

Stripslashes also didnt worked. 
Checked $item->extra_fields is a string type

Comment: `echo $json` and show how it looks like

Comment: What does `var_dump($myArray);` show?

Comment: $myArray = json_decode($json, true); <- is it because you want an array instead of an object? Add second arg.

Comment: Most likely magic_quotes problem. Try `stripslashes`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your code, nor with the JSON data you're trying to decode, but is a PHP configuration error (or done on purpose). I've come across this multiple times, but simply put *the function has been disabled*. **Note** that the function is not working rather than actually disabled, but the result is the same, an empty return value.

Best solution is to use an alternative code (method) to decode your JSON data, which can be found on the PHP website:

```
function json_decode($json)
{
    $comment = false;
    $out = '$x=';

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($json); $i++)
    {
        if (!$comment)
        {
            if (($json[$i] == '{') || ($json[$i] == '[')) $out .= ' array(';
            else if (($json[$i] == '}') || ($json[$i] == ']')) $out .= ')';
            else if ($json[$i] == ':') $out .= '=>';
            else $out .= $json[$i];
        }
        else $out .= $json[$i];
        if ($json[$i] == '"' && $json[($i-1)]!="\\") $comment = !$comment;
    }

    eval($out . ';');
    return $x;
}
```

This code is not pretty, but it does the trick. I've used this code every now and then to decode JSON data on servers that have similar problems you describe and I've yet to come across data you can't decode using this function.

Answer (score 0):

@KilZone: Thanks for the reply. I haven't tried your code, but the string that was being fetched from the database was showing properly in the brower, but when i checked it by viewing the source, the string was having `&quot;` instead of double quote.

So I just used the below code to replace, and it solved my problem.

```
json_decode(str_replace("&quot;","\"",$item->extra_fields))
```

Thank you everyone for the reply.